# Sagemaker Studio trial component chart not showing

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am wondering why I am unable to show the loss and accuracy curve in Sagemaker Studio, Trial components chart.

I am using tensorflow's keras API for training.

```py
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow


estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point="sm_entrypoint.sh",
    source_dir=".",
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.4xlarge",
    framework_version="2.4",
    py_version="py37",
    metric_definitions=[
            {'Name':'train:loss', 'Regex':'loss: ([0-9.]+'},
            {'Name':'val:loss', 'Regex':'val_loss: ([0-9.]+'},
            {'Name':'train:accuracy', 'Regex':'accuracy: ([0-9.]+'},
            {'Name':'val:accuracy', 'Regex':'val_accuracy: ([0-9.]+'}
        ],
    enable_sagemaker_metrics=True
)
 

estimator.fit(
    inputs="s3://xxx",
    experiment_config={
        "ExperimentName": "urbansounds-20211027",
        "TrialName": "tf-classical-NN-20211027",
        "TrialComponentDisplayName": "Train"
    }
)
```

Regex is enabled, and appears to be logging them correctly. Since under the metrics tab, it shows 12 counts for each metric, corresponding to 12 epochs cycle which I specified.

[image]

However, the chart is empty. The x-axis is in time here, but it is also empty when I switched to epoch.

[image]

Comment: Same question. The logged metrics in a trial component are all aggregated to their mean, min, max etc, instead of individual values, and the trainigjob (the trial component) expects Epoch to be defined in some way, which is not documented anywhere.

Nobody seems to have the answer, and nobody seems to care. SageMaker Experiment is just a terrible tool that nobody uses. A bit of "Customer Obsession" can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: in your `entry_point` source code `sm_entrypoint.sh`, you need to explicitly inform the experiment tracker which epoch the metric is associated with, using the `log_metric()` function.

There are two ways tracker work in SageMaker Experiment Tracker: (1) you log the metric in your `entry_point` code, and use `metric_definitions` argument in the estimator to teach SM to parse the metric from the logs, as the way you did it, or, you can (2) explicitly create a Tracker instance *inside* your `entry_point`, and invoke the `log_metric()` method. Apparently only method (2) tells SM Tracker what epoch each metric entry is registered to.

I found the answer from a random video https://youtu.be/gMnkfPztIHU?t=141, after days of search :(

Oh there is also a catch: SageMaker images do not have the Tracker package installed, so if you just have `from smexperiments.tracker import Tracker` in your `entry_point` source code, your SM Estimator will complain. So you will need to install `sagemaker-experiments` for your image, by

1. create a `requirements.txt` file that has `sagemaker-experiments==0.1.35` in it;
2. specify the source dir by including `source_dir="./dir_that_contains_requirements.txt"` in your estimator creation.